# Deleted home page by mistake drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

So I created a custom page (which became my site's home page). I modified this page and added some content to it but wasn't  happy with it so I decided to delete it. Unfortunately now, my home page is gone along with whatever was originally on it. Now whenever I try and go to my home page, it says 'Page not found'. Is there any way I could get it back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore default homepage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371250/how-to-restore-default-homepage)

Comment: go to /admin/config/system/site-information and set new home page url

Comment: I very much doubt you can recover your deleted database entry for it, assuming that when you delete a page it literally does delete the db entry. That being said, as the comment above me says, you can always restore the default one or set a different page to your new home page

Comment: Setting the home page url worked. Thank you